# Fullcalendar associate events from resources with a flat array(no nested)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-4

I would like to add an event to the row used by fullcalendar for grouping.

I have seen that this is possible through nested array, but through ***flat array***?

Here the desired

[image: **enter image description here**]

If I use **nested array**, this is possibile because every child has an id

```
{"id":"d","title":"Auditorium D","children":[{"id":"d1","title":"Room D1"},{"id":"d2","title":"Room D2"}]},{"id":"e","title":"Auditorium E"}
```

But in **flat array** group by key, for example *building* and there is no key, so I don't understand how link an event to it

```
resources: [
  { id: 'a', building: '460 Bryant', title: 'Auditorium A' },
  { id: 'b', building: '460 Bryant', title: 'Auditorium B' },
],
```

Here the codepen:

> https://codepen.io/irrech/pen/rNabjOe?editors=0010

Comment: please don't upload _pictures_ of your code...they're unhelpful. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Code is text. Paste it as text, please.

Comment: Anyway the answer to your question is, you can't do it using the structure you've defined. Moreover how/why do you think it would be possible? You aren't creating a resource, you're just grouping the resources by a common value, for display purposes. There's no ID for the resource, so you can't add events to it.

Comment: However, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource-parsing tells you how to create nested resources, but using a flat array (see the last section)